# Reading a csv File into JS Array convert to JSON

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

I am reading data from a simple csv file and adding some data from a web service into an array using Node JS fs.  The array is defined as:

```
var allDataOut=[];
```

The addition of the data happens at this point in the code:

```
var cumulate = {
            "Details":augment,
            "Timestamp": new Date(),
            data:data
        }
        allDataOut.push(cumulate);
        console.log(allDataOut);
        callback(cumulate);
```

According to the console.log I am seeing exactly what I would expect  with the correct data sitting inside the [] denoting an array.

So to create a JSON I would expect the JSON.stringify(allDataOut) would give me the correct result.

```
console.log("writing file");
        var str = JSON.stringify(allDataOut);
        console.log("This is output .stringify" + str);

        fs.appendFileSync(outputFile, str, encoding='utf8');
```

but as you can see in the final data below it is still in the array format. I have seen a number of questions on this subject in this forum with one suggestion of using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(allDataOut)); - unfortunately nothing seems to change the output.

```
[ {
    "Details": {
      "Name": "Tophat",
      "SegmentID": "0",
      "DistanceToDepot": "256.53"
    },
    "Timestamp": "2016-04-10T11:40:03.291Z",
    "data": {
      "metadata": {
        "language": "en-US",
        "transaction_id": "1460288403143:279662660",
        "version": "1",
        "Altitude": 49.44
      },
      "observation": {
        "class": "observation",
        "expire_time_gmt": 1460289003,
        "metric": {
          "wspd": 21,
          "gust": null,
          "vis": 9.7
        }
      }
    }   },   {
    "Details": {
      "Name": "Tophat",
      "SegmentID": "25659",
      "DistanceToDepot": "0"
    },
    "Timestamp": "2016-04-10T11:40:40.428Z",
    "data": {
      "metadata": {
        "language": "en-US",
        "transaction_id": "1460288440297:-647605523",
        "version": "1",
        "Altitude": 50.68
      },
      "observation": {
        "class": "observation",
        "expire_time_gmt": 1460288452,
        "metric": {
          "wspd": 18,
          "gust": null,
          "vis": 12.91
        }
      }
    }   } ]
```

Comment: What's the problem the data is valid json. Do you maybe want a JSON object which contains a json array. You can validate json on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: **I am seeing exactly what I would expect with the correct data sitting inside the [] denoting an array** then **but as you can see in the final data below it is still in the array format**. You're expecting an array then you're surprised when you get one?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It is a json array which I thought the json.stringify would convert to a row by row series of json objects. I am told the application used to read this file will read a json object but not an array. I'll research how to convert a json array to json objects.

Answer (score 0):

So to suit the nature of the application reading the data the format need to have the data in a line by line. Being new to JSON I believe this does not create a JSON array per se but a series of JSON objects inside the file.  And learnt how to do an EOL and iterate in Node JS.
To achieve this I added a EOL in the stringify as per below.

```
console.log("writing file");
        for(var i in allDataOut)
        {
            fs.appendFileSync(outputFile, JSON.stringify(allDataOut[i]) + '\r\n', encoding='utf8');

        }    
        console.log("done");
```